# Django authenticate() resets password

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a weird problem here. When I login, it works well as expected but when I try to logout and try to login again, it says that my password is invalid.

I checked my User table and it's really changing my password everytime I use authenticate() function.

I got this error a month ago (still django 1.8 at that time) but gone after many testing and tracing and praying and didn't have a single idea what happened. It only occurs in my local machine though.

---

**authentication.py**

after authenticate() function, my password is already changed (tried to put a breakpoint after the function so I know for sure that this is the culprit).

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout, login

def signin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        result = {}
        data = req_data(request)
        try:
            user = authenticate(username = data['email'], password = data['password'])
            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    #return success for redirection
                else:
                    raise ValueError("This user is inactive. Please contact your admin.")
            else:
                raise ValueError("Invalid username/password.")
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse(e, status = 400)
    else:
        return redirect("login")

def signout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("login")

#gets the params from ajax post
def req_data(request):
    return json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8")) if request.body.decode("utf-8") else {}
```

I checked the DB and got this result.

**Old Password**

> pbkdf2_sha256$20000$N4esMaOT5BYi$nIehHw63b+iZSz2Vmu1hEO10BqPfzAGu1cZA1ci/nXI=

**New Password** (After login)

> pbkdf2_sha256$24000$KVZeuG4pgSkv$VIenbuq0Wk8sYZros4kE4Q7W0Jt+bOC23ha4/VSOXV8=

---

**EDIT:**

for the meantime, I am not using authenticate() and just use a generic password.

```
username = data.get('email',"")
password = data.get('password',"")
if password == "genericpassword123":
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email = username)
        user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise ValueError("Invalid username/password.")
else:
    user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)

if user:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        #return success for redirection
    else:
        raise ValueError("This user is inactive. Please contact your admin.")
else:
    raise ValueError("Invalid username/password.")
```

Python 2.7

Django 1.9

Postgre 9.4

Thanks!

Comment: One can't possibly  tell what the problem is from that single line. Do show your `logout` and `login` views

Comment: And show how you are verifying that your password is "changed".

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Kindly see the updated question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman kindly see the updated question.

Comment: The hash is different because Django is increasing the iteration count (you're upgrading Django from 1.8?). That doesn't change the password that matches the hash, so the login error is most likely due to some other error. Can you show your `req_data()` function? What are you using the `hashers` module for? You usually don't need to interact with this module directly.

Comment: Yes, I just upgraded it from 1.8. Don't mind the hashers, I didn't use it. See the edited question. Thanks!

Comment: @knbk I got this error a month ago (still django 1.8 that time) but gone after many testing and tracing and didn't have a single idea what happened. It only occurs in my local machine though.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now. I never thought that it works in different account with different password.